# ObservableList conception for regular variables (without TableView)

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

In the every example I find for JavaFX there is `TableView` (with `setCellValueFactory` on `TableColumn` and `setItems` on `TableView`).

How can I do a single observable object?

For example, if I have following fxml (values would be changed by a third party controller):

```
<fx:root type="GridPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="AStringAndAnIntController">
    <Label text="random string" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Label fx:id="str" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Label text="random int" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Label fx:id="integer" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
</fx:root>
```

and an model object:

```
public class AStringAndAnInt{
    private String str;
    private int integer;
    //with its setters and getters
}
```

What should I do in the controller to link my object with JavaFX controls?

```
public class AStringAndAnIntController extends GridPane implements Initializable{
    @FXML Label str;
    @FXML Label integer;

    @Override public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){
    }
    public void setAStringAndAnInt(AStringAndAnInt strint){
        //what would go inside? a ObserbableList.add(strint)?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [JavaFX properties and binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) to have observable values.

```
public class AStringAndAnInt{
    private StringProperty str = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private IntegerProperty integer = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public String getStr() {
        return str.getValue();
    }

    public void setStr(String value) {
        str.set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty strProperty() {
        return str;
    }

    public int getInteger() {
        return integer.getValue();
    }

    public void setInteger(int value) {
        integer.set(value);
    }

    public IntegerProperty integerProperty() {
        return integer;
    }
}
```

So in your controller you can write:

```
public class AStringAndAnIntController extends GridPane implements Initializable{
    @FXML Label str;
    @FXML Label integer;

    @Override public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){
    }
    public void setAStringAndAnInt(AStringAndAnInt strint){
        str.textProperty().bind(strint.strProperty());
        integer.textProperty().bind(strint.integerProperty().asString());
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, simple as that and i was trying really weird things with ObservableList

Comment: tried it, the string one works perfectly, but with the integer one i get the error: "The method bindBidirectional(Property<String>) in the type StringProperty is not applicable for the arguments (StringBinding)", seems that `asString()` turns it into `StringBinding` and the bind doesn't work with it. Just got also a new question, edited the main post if possible to help with it too

Comment: that's a totally another question, so ask it separately, please. Removed bidirectional from answer, sorry for that error.